# Find closest class and reload it AJAX jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, closest

This is a "LIKE" system similar to Facebook.

I've got an html layout with multiple links where each one looks something like this when rendered :

```
 <a class="like-comment-link" href="#" data-id="278">
 <span class="like-comment"></span></a>
 <span class="likes">Bob, John and Peter like this</span>
```

I'm using AJAX to insert and delete the likes into the database, this is all working great. But I'm having trouble targeting the "likes" class from the ajax script to update the names of the people that liked it.

I basically need something which does the following :

```
 $(this).closest(".likes").find(".likes").load(location.href + " .likes");
```

I know this doesn't work but I don't know the correct way to code it.

Basically, on a successful like or unlike I need jQuery to find the closest instance of ".likes" to the parent which is ".like-comment-link" and then reload that class only on this element.

**EDIT**

Including AJAX script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', "a.like-comment-link", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $self = $(this);

    var data = {
        post_id: $self.data('id'),
        nonce: likecom.nonce,
        action: 'comment_likes'
    };

    $self.addClass('loading');

    $.post(likecom.ajaxurl, data, function(res) {

        if (res.success) {
            $self.html(res.data);
            $self.siblings(".likes").load(location.href + " .likes");

        } else {
            alert("It went tits up!");
        }

        $self.removeClass('loading');
    });
  });  
});
```

If this is overly complicated I could change target class' name to include the id of the current item like this :

```
 <span class="likes-278">....</span>
```

But I can't figure out how to concatenate strings in jQuery.

I tried a few things like this :

```
 $(".likes-" + $self.data('id')).load(location.href + " .likes-" + $self.data('id'));
```

But that obviously didn't work.

Maybe somebody could show me how to correctly formulate this in the AJAX script?

Comment: where's the ajax code? Return the data when you post it. No need to make another request with `load()`

Comment: It's complicated. It's pulling the user info from a completely different source in the originating php script. Was causing errors all over the place when I tried returning the function via ajax. load() is working without a problem though.

Comment: you don't return a function, just the updated text or html or as json

Comment: This is the problem, the function that gets the names is long and overly complex. It's not done with JS. It's all being grabbed from the database and then run through a whole bunch of if else statements to output the correct format. "You like this", "You and Robert like this", "You, Robert, Dave and 13 others like this". Was an absolute nightmare to get it working but it does, php wise.

Comment: Well another way you could do it is in that php add the `You like this` part also. Put it in a data attribute and set the text from the data attribute after first ajax. Otherwise change `closest()` to `next().load()` in your jQuery

Comment: Hmm I'm trying **$(this).next(".likes").load(location.href + " .likes");** but nothing is happening? Have I got that wrong?

Comment: assuming the html is exactly as shown and `this` is the `<a>` it should be right.

Comment: Actually there is another span in the mix before it, so I tried nextAll but that didn't work either. I'll update the question to show the extra span tag.

Comment: then use `siblings()` if they are on same level

Comment: Instead of next? Sorry, still learning jQuery here

Comment: Just tried **$(this).siblings(".likes").load(location.href + " .likes");** but again, not working.

Comment: where are you using `this`? if it's in an ajax callback it won't be the element. Show all relevant code

Comment: Yes I just realised that, I've changed it to self.siblings and now it's targeting the correct instance but reloading the content of all instances of "like" on the page into this instance. Will post ajax code in question.

Comment: that's why you would normally return just what is needed from the original request

Comment: Ahh ok. Added the AJAX above. Maybe I'm just doing it all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this. Since the span is always after the anchor element in your example, you may also use `.next()` function to locate the element

```
$('.like-comment-link').on("click",function()
{
    if($(this).next("span").hasClass("likes"))
    {
        $(this).next("span").removeClass("likes");
        $(this).next("span").addClass("nolikes");
        // Write value to db
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).next("span").removeClass("nolikes");
        $(this).next("span").addClass("likes");
        // Write value to db
    }        
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3k0vLdt4/3/

Hope it helps doing what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks DinoMyte, I totally get what you are saying but it doesn't help me in this instance, I need to reload just the instance of "likes" relevant to this post. If I did it your way all I would be doing is checking if the class existed and then reload all instances of "likes" on the page, which is exactly the problem I am having now. I just need to target this particular instance of "class" and reload only that one.